# No data in the collectionview method

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

My application functions correctly, but due to the absence of data being received in the `UICollectionView`, the application crashes. In the `UITableView`, the data is displayed and received correctly. Here's my code.

```
import UIKit

extension WeatherViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print(weatherData)
        guard let currentData = weatherData else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        let cell: WeatherCell
        let cellIdentifier: String

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            cellIdentifier = "WindCell"
        case 1:
            cellIdentifier = "PressureCell"
        case 2:
            cellIdentifier = "PrecipitationCell"
        case 3:
            cellIdentifier = "HumidityCell"
        default:
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        if let reusableCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? WeatherCell {
            cell = reusableCell
        } else {
            print("Failed to dequeue \(cellIdentifier)")
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            cell.configure(with: "Wind", quantity: "\(currentData.current.windKph)", imageName: "wind")
        case 1:
            cell.configure(with: "Pressure", quantity: "\(currentData.current.pressureMb)", imageName: "pressure")
        case 2:
            cell.configure(with: "Precipitation", quantity: "\(currentData.current.precipMm)", imageName: "precipitation")
        case 3:
            cell.configure(with: "Humidity", quantity: "\(currentData.current.humidity)", imageName: "humidity")
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

```
class WeatherViewController: UIViewController {
    private var weatherPresenter: WeatherPresenter?
    var weatherData: Weather?
    
    lazy var currentWeatherLabel = UILabel()
    lazy var celciusLabel = UILabel()
    lazy var currentCityLabel = UILabel()
    lazy var currentConditionLabel = UILabel()
    lazy var feelsLikeLabel = UILabel()
    lazy var forecastTableView = UITableView()
    lazy var currentCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        return UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        forecastTableView.dataSource = self
        forecastTableView.delegate = self
        forecastTableView.register(ForecastWeatherCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ForecastWeatherCell")
        
        currentCollectionView.delegate = self
        currentCollectionView.dataSource = self
        currentCollectionView.register(WindCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "WindCell")
        currentCollectionView.register(PressureCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PrecipitationCell")
        currentCollectionView.register(PrecipitationCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PressureCell")
        currentCollectionView.register(HumidityCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HumidityCell")

        weatherPresenter = WeatherPresenter(weatherViewDelegate: self)
        weatherPresenter?.getWeatherForCurrentLocation()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupUi()
    }
}
```

```
extension WeatherViewController: WeatherViewDelegate {
    func updateWeather(_ weatherData: Weather) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.weatherData = weatherData
            self.currentWeatherLabel.text = "\(Int(weatherData.current.tempC))"
            self.celciusLabel.isHidden = false
            self.currentCityLabel.text = "\(weatherData.location.name)"
            self.currentConditionLabel.text = "\(weatherData.current.condition.text)"
            self.forecastTableView.isHidden = false
            self.feelsLikeLabel.text = "Feels like: \(Int(weatherData.current.feelslikeC))°"
            
            if let todayIndex = self.weatherData?.forecast.forecastday.firstIndex(where: { $0.date == weatherData.forecast.forecastday[0].date }) {
                self.weatherData?.forecast.forecastday.remove(at: todayIndex)
            }
            
            self.forecastTableView.reloadData()
            self.currentCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func showError(message: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Ошибка", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ОК", style: .default)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it might be related to a data race, but that's not the case.

Comment: You should edit your original question, rather than asking a new question, to provide details or clarification. You also still haven't provided the details in the crash message and on which line the crash occurs.

Comment: Also, dequeuing cells is one place where you can justify using a force downcast. Better to have your app crash during development with an obvious indication as to the problem. Dequeuing cells won't just suddenly fail in release.

Comment: @Paulw11 Exception NSException * "the cell returned from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: does not have a reuseIdentifier - cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath. But this error is occurring because weatherData is nil, even though I have implemented a UITableView where weatherData arrives correctly

Comment: It's because on first load, `weatherData` is nil (since you have a `print` you can check it), so you call `return UICollectionViewCell()`, which isn't really allowed. It's happening because you say you should show 4 cells even if weatherData isn't there...

Answer (score 0):

The collection view is obviously reloaded before your data is fetched.

The simplest approach is to return 0 cells when the data is empty:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return weatherData != nil ? 4 : 0
}
```

Also you may consider having a placeholder cell that is displayed in case the Weather data is nil. The simplest approach is to register a regular `UICollectionViewCell` as a placeholder, or the one with custom design.

Register placeholder along with other cells:

```
currentCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell")
```

Return proper count:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return weatherData != nil ? 4 : 1
}
```

Then dequeue it when the data is empty:

```
guard let currentData = weatherData else {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PlaceholderCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cell
}
```